# .NET MVC how to retrieve a Model in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a List of product and a customer object coming from my server. I want to retrieve that information on javascript.

```
  <!-- Customer object -->
  <input type="hidden" id="customer" value="@ViewBag.Customer">

  <!-- List of products -->
  <input type="hidden" id="products" value="@Model">
```

Now in my javascript I have this.

```
console.log(document.getElementById("customer").value);
```

Thats not working I don't get the object value. I want to know how I reach the desire result?

The source code...

```
<!-- Customer object -->
  <input type="hidden" id="customer" value="Namespace.Models.Customer">

  <!-- List of products -->
  <input type="hidden" id="products" value="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Namespace.Models.Product]">
```

This is my server side code.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Order(int customerId)
    {
        ViewBag.Customer = await customerRepository.Details(customerId);
        var product = await productRepository.GetAll();

        return View(products);
    }
```

Comment: Does the HTML rendered  has proper value attribute for these inputs ? (Check view source)

Comment: What is your HTML source looks like after _rendered_..?

Comment: Why are you setting and trying to read the entire model (A complex class) in javascript ? What are you trying to do with it ?

Comment: I want to read the model in javascript.

Comment: You mean the entire Model object  ?

Comment: Yes, I added the server side code so you can see what needs to be view.

Comment: This looks like Razor pages and the traditional Razor views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments, it looks like you want to read the entire model object in javascript, you may create a json string from your model using your javascript serializor.

Here is an example using

```
<script>
    var model = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
    console.log(model);       
</script>
```

The variable `model` will contain a js object(dictionary style) representing your razor view's model object.

Since we are executing C# exression/methods, (`Html.Raw`, `SerializeObject`), The above code has to be inside a razor view, not in an external javascript file(via a global variable). You can still access the object inside the external js file as long as that file is included after setting the js object to a global variable

Comment: I'm using .net core I don't believe .net core has tag helpers.

Comment: What tag helper are you talking about ?

Comment: Why not use `@Json.Encode(Model)`? It's also worth mentioning that `@Html.Raw()` is really only needed when you don't want to have special characters escaped, which Razor will escape for you by default.

Comment: `@Html.Raw()` is needed even if you do not have special characters in your model property values. Otherwise razor will encode `"`" to `&quot;`, resulting in a script error.

Answer (score 0):

There are few tweaks you need to do in order to achieve your desired results:

1. Strongly bind your MVC View by specifying the model at the top of your .cshtml file

   `@model List<StackOverflow.Models.Product>`
2. Modify your javascript code to parse  customer details and products list into a valid JSON data type

   ```
    var customerDetails = @Html.Raw(@Json.Encode(ViewBag.Customer));

    // Read products list by directly referencing Model as view is strongly-typed
    var productsList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

   console.log("First Product Name:  " + productsList[0].Name);
   ```

Also, I believe there is no need to have hidden HTML elements for storing any information coming from the server or any other source. This will increase the size of your page resulting in poor performance.

In addition, rather than sending data into ViewBag's, you can simply create a ViewModel and have CustomerDetails and ProductsList as properties and then parse the model directly as shown above.